# How to install firefox on AWS ubuntu codebuild?

Tags: firefox, aws

I have been trying to install firefox on an ubuntu image with the following command in an AWS buildspec.yml file

```
...
- apt-get install firefox
...
```

I get this error on AWS codebuild:

```
[Container] 2018/12/03 10:57:42 Command did not exit successfully apt-get 
install firefox exit status 100
[Container] 2018/12/03 10:57:42 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: false
[Container] 2018/12/03 10:57:42 Phase context status code: 
COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: apt-get install firefox. Reason: exit status 100
```

Are there any repositories I need to add to the build? If so which ones?

Comment: IIRC apt-get requires an interactive session (so that you can answer y/n to install). Try `apt-get install firefox -y` instead.

Comment: @LewisSmith thanks for the tip, it still fails with the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally worked out that in the AWS buildspec.yml file, these were the lines I needed:

```
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox wget
- export FIREFOX_BIN=/usr/bin/firefox
```

Now, I can run my Angular project Karma tests with Firefox on AWS codebuild.